# Using Windows 7, getting Vmware XP drivers working

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

I am using Windows-7 (64-bit) Home edition.
I have a old USB device that comes with only windows XP drivers (which I really want to get this working).

Therefore, I plan to install Windows-XP (32-bit) on Vmware workstation.
However, from my understanding, in order for any USB device to work on the Vmware XP (32-bit),
the driver must first be recongize by Windows-7 (main computer).

Am I correct about this? If so, is there any solution getting a old XP driver working on Windows 7 in any fashion?

Or is there any method to connect the USB device directly to Vmware XP (without even getting it to recongize by Windows-7)

Please advise. Much appreciated. Million thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a USB device through to the guest OS without any drivers.